# How to create a read-only list in java without using unmodifiablelist method from collections API?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

An interviewer asked me this question to create a read-only list in java without using collections API method.Any thoughts on how we can achieve this ?

Comment: Subclass it and throw an `Exception` in the mutable methods - I also think `Arrays#asList` generates a readonly `List`

Comment: Using unmodifiableList() of collection class

Comment: @MadProgrammer `Arrays.asList()` allows `set()` calls to modify the list.

Comment: I went with `unmofifiablelist()` -- I'm curious as to What part of the unmodifiablelist sub-class you need to avoid?

Answer (score 6):

Just extend [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html). As the docs mention:

> To implement an **unmodifiable** list, the programmer needs only to extend
>   this class and provide implementations for the get(int) and size()
>   methods.

Comment: Good one. For further info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html

Comment: @Ramanlfc -  If i will provide the implementation of only get(int) and size() methods, and not of add method. Then how will i create a list in the first place?

Comment: @MohdFaizanKhan In that case the constructor must use its parameters to create the list.

Answer (score 2):

I have been asked the same question in an interview, and I came up with some code which works fine in my case and interviewer got convinced.

**Employee Class**

```
public final class Employee {
 private int age;
 private String name;
 private double salary;
 public Employee(int age, String name, double salary){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.salary=salary;
 }

 public int getAge() {
    return age;
 }
 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }
 public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
 }
}
```

**EmployeeList Class**

```
public class EmployeeList extends AbstractList<Employee>{

private ArrayList<Employee> list;

 public EmployeeList(ArrayList<Employee> list){
    this.list=list;
 }

 @Override
 public Employee get(int i) {
    return this.list.get(i);
 }

 @Override
 public int size() {
    return this.list.size();
 }

}
```

**EmployeeListUtility Class**

```
public class EmployeeListUtility {
 private EmployeeList employeeList;
 public EmployeeList getImmutableEmployeeList(ArrayList<Employee> employeeList) {
    this.employeeList = new EmployeeList(employeeList);
    return this.employeeList;
 }

}
```

**Runner Class**

```
public class RunnerClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Employee> listOfEmployees=new ArrayList<>();
    listOfEmployees.add(new Employee(1, "Faizan", 1000));
    listOfEmployees.add(new Employee(2, "Arun", 1000));
    listOfEmployees.add(new Employee(3, "Amit", 1000));
    listOfEmployees.add(new Employee(4, "Noman", 1000));
    listOfEmployees.add(new Employee(5, "John", 1000));

    //till now listOfEmployee is mutable

    EmployeeListUtility employeeListUtility=new EmployeeListUtility();
    EmployeeList employeeList=employeeListUtility.getImmutableEmployeeList(listOfEmployees);
    //now employeeList object is immutable. 
    System.out.println(employeeList.size()); //print 5
    employeeList.clear();  //will throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
}

}
```

Now with **employeeList** object in runner class, if you try to access any other method of **AbstractList** which you have not implemented in **EmployeeList** Class, then it will throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

which means your employeeList is immutable now.

Answer (score 0):

I have overridden `get(int)` and `size()`, but `addPerson` is still able to add new `String`s to the `ArrayList`.

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UnmodifyableList extends AbstractList
{
    public UnmodifyableList()
    {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList .add("Artyom");
        arrayList .add("Natasha");
        arrayList .add("Anton");
        arrayList .add("Dasha");
    }

    @Override
    public String get(int i)
    {
        return arrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public void addPerson()
    {
        arrayList.add("testname");
    }
}
```

but when I delete `addPerson()` and use methods inherited from `AbstractList`, yes, it turns out that the `ArrayList` cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I try some thing like below, hope it will help:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class ImutableList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<Integer> lsd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lsd.add(1);
        lsd.add(2);
        lsd.add(3);
        lsd.add(4);

        ImList imList = new ImList(lsd);
        imList.getLis().add(5);
        imList.getLis().add(6);
        imList.getLis().add(7);
        imList.getLis().add(8);

        for (int k : imList.getLis()) {
            System.out.println(k);
        }
// output will: 1 2 3 4 only    

        }

    static class ImList extends AbstractList<Integer> {

        private final List<Integer> list;

        public ImList(List list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.list.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.list.size();
        }

        public List<Integer> getLis() {
            return new ArrayList<>(list);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: FYI ArrayList implements cloneable interface, so no need of writing all of this.